# How to dynamically override a method in an object

Tags: java, overriding

If this is possible, how can I change what a method does after I might have created an instance of that class and wish to keep the reference to that object but *override* a public method in it's class' definition?

> Here's my code:

```
    package time_applet;

    public class TimerGroup implements Runnable{

        private Timer hour, min, sec;
        private Thread hourThread, minThread, secThread;

        public TimerGroup(){
            hour = new HourTimer();
            min = new MinuteTimer();
            sec = new SecondTimer();
        }


        public void run(){
            hourThread.start();
            minThread.start();
            secThread.start();
        }

/*Please pay close attention to this method*/
        private Timer activateHourTimer(int start_time){
            hour = new HourTimer(start_time){

                public void run(){
                    while (true){

                        if(min.changed)//min.getTime() == 0)
                            changeTime();

                    }

                }
            };
            hourThread = new Thread(hour);
            return hour;
        }

        private Timer activateMinuteTimer(int start_time){

            min = new MinuteTimer(start_time){
                public void run(){
                    while (true){

                        if(sec.changed)//sec.getTime() == 0)
                            changeTime();

                    }

                }
            };
            minThread = new Thread(min);    
            return min;
        }

        private Timer activateSecondTimer(int start_time){
            sec = new SecondTimer(start_time);
            secThread = new Thread(sec);
            return sec;
        }

        public Timer addTimer(Timer timer){
            if (timer instanceof HourTimer){
                hour = timer;
                return activateHourTimer(timer.getTime());
            }
            else if (timer instanceof MinuteTimer){
                min = timer;
                return activateMinuteTimer(timer.getTime());
            }
            else{
                sec = timer;
                return activateSecondTimer(timer.getTime());        
            }
        }
    }
```

So for example in the method activateHourTimer(), I would like to override the run() method of the hour object without having to create a new object. How do I go about that?

Comment: Use the inheritance, extend the object you want to override.

Comment: As sometimes happens, you have a problem and have thought of a sort-of way to do it, but can't make it work.  So you ask how to make that sort-of way to do it work.  But if you were to tell us about the original problem, you would be more likely to get a better suggestion, particularly since (as also often happens) your sort-of way doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not override same method more then one time in the same class and you are creating an annonymous class of HourTimer.

```
      hour = new HourTimer(start_time){

            public void run(){
                while (true){

                    if(min.changed)//min.getTime() == 0)
                        changeTime();

                }

            }
        };
```

you can do it in another way by putting an if else condition inside activateHourTimer method as fallows-

```
     private Timer activateHourTimer(int start_time){
       if(Condition1){
           hour = new HourTimer(start_time){

              public void run(){
                  while (true){

                      //First Condition
                  }

              }
          };
       }else if(Condition2){
           hour = new HourTimer(start_time){

              public void run(){
                  while (true){

                      //Second Condition
                  }

              }
          };
       }else{
           hour = new HourTimer(start_time){

              public void run(){
                  while (true){

                      //Third Condition
                  }

              }
          };
       }
        hourThread = new Thread(hour);
        return hour;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't override a method of a local (anonymous) class, but you can override the whole method via an anonymous class:

```
TimerGroup customTimerGroup = new TimerGroup() {
    private Timer activateHourTimer(int start_time) {
        hour = new HourTimer(start_time){ 
            public void run() {
                // do something different
            }
        };
        hourThread = new Thread(hour);
        return hour;
    }
};
```